# Add OAuth scope for connected app in managed package

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps

Recently I've added new OAuth scope for connected app in managed package. Everything was good, clients were able to install the package via the direct link. The problem appeared when I tried to push upgrade this package to clients. It turned out according to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm) new OAuth scopes will fail push upgrade, only installation via direct link is allowed.

Installation via the link isn't a real scenario for me, because we have too many customers. But on the other hand, we have to somehow propagate new package version with new OAuth scope.

So did anybody have the same situation? In what way did you deal with it?

Comment: Hi, Oleg. How did you end up solving this? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @MintoTsai, if I'm not mistaken we created a new Connected App with the desired number of OAuth scopes because even Salesforce didn't suggest us anything but asking hundreds of our customers to install a new package version via the link. If you create a new Connected App, there's another problem because even if you push upgrade all the customers, there's a number of the client's orgs that are in a stop list or can't be upgraded because of some reasons, so after the upgrade, you will have to support connection via both Connected Apps. It was a real pain in the ass

Comment: Thanks for the details, Oleg. What a pain.